# Массив пустеет за пределами метода

Tags: android, firebase

Собираюсь вывести списком в ListFragment имена и фамилии из массива `namesArray`. В массив записываются имена и фамилии из базы данных, но за пределами слушателя массив снова пустеет, он передается в адаптер и список отображаемый ListFragment пуст, почему?
Ведь массив инициализирован в теле класса:

```
public class SingleListFragment extends ListFragment {

private DatabaseReference myRef;

ArrayList<String> namesArray;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    namesArray = new ArrayList();

    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    myRef.child("items").addValueEventListener(

            new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        MainActivity.Item item = postSnapshot.getValue(MainActivity.Item.class);

                        String currentID = postSnapshot.getKey();

                        String currentName = item.name;
                        String currentSecName = item.secName;

                        namesArray.add(currentName + ' ' + currentSecName);

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }

            });

    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namesArray);
    setListAdapter(adapter);


}
```

Comment: можно через синглтон сделать, сетить массив там, а потом оттуда же его и вытаскивать, независимо от других классов он будет там постоянно

Comment: Массив заполняется по событию и на момент создания адаптера - пустой. Добавьте строчку `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` внутри листенера. Ну и сам адаптер либо перенесите до листенера и сделайте `final`, либо сделайте его глобальным

Comment: @Jarvis_J подскажите, для чего листенер делать final?

Comment: для того, чтобы к нему был доступ внутри анонимного класса (попробуйте без `final`)